# What is the categorical construction for a list of nested lists?

Tags: category-theory, monads

In Category Theory, the `List` functor is the Free Monoid over a given type (i.e. object) `T`. One can then consider the category of endofunctors over types and define a monad over the functor `List`, where the $\mu$ natural transformation is responsible for flattening the list of lists into a simple list (e.g. [[1],[2],[3]] -> [1,2,3]).

Now, I'm interested in something a bit more general. I want to be able to construct list with arbitrary "nesting" and then flatten it (e.g. [1,[2,3],[[4],5]] -> [1,2,3,4,5]).

At first, I thought that this case would be covered by the List Monad... But it seems not to be the case. Indeed, if we think of [1,[2,3]], this is of type `List Union{Int, List{Int}}`, and not a `List List Int`... Thus, the $\mu$ function does not work...

Finally, my question is what is the Category Theory interpretation of such "arbitrary" list of lists.

Comment: Not really :/, but thanks

Comment: I'm not super familiar with this, but we also have a map Int->List Int sending x to [x], right? This would also define a map Union{Int, List Int}->List Int and therefore a map List Union{Int, List Int}->List List Int, which we can then flatten

Comment: What you have described is something akin to the monad that governs free non symmetric operads. Your list is a planar tree where a list spawns a new vertex whose children can be lists, etc. Flattening consists of sending the given tree to the unique corolla it defines by contracting internal edges to have length $0$. You original example is doing this for associative algebras instead of operads.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't, by definition, the map $\mu:T^2\implies T$ exactly this "flattening" map?

Comment: @FShrike: the multiplication for the list monad will only flatten "lists of lists", i.e. balanced trees of depth 2, rather than arbitrary depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view arbitrarily-nested lists as representing an [ordered tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Plane_tree). This is also known as a [rose tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_tree) (though that term appears to be used in several contexts). The ordered tree construction forms a monad, where the unit is given by the singleton tree, and the multiplication is given by interpreting "ordered trees whose leaves are ordered trees" simply as ordered trees. Algebraically, the list monad is given by the free [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) construction, while the ordered tree monad is given by the free (nonsymmetric) [operad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad) construction. There is a monad morphism from the ordered tree monad to the list monad, given by flattening the ordered tree: this is the flattening construction you describe.

As you suspect, the free monad on the list functor is the ordered tree monad (e.g. as mentioned [in these slides](https://www.ioc.ee/%7Etarmo/monads-more/monads-more-2.pdf)).

Comment: Does this has any relation with Free Monads? Would you know if the list monad is perhaps the "terminal" object in some subcategory of monads? Perhaps monads over monoids or something.

Comment: @DaviBarreira: just as the list monad is the free monoid monad, the ordered tree monad is the free "multiary magma" monad, where a multiary [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) is a set equipped with an $n$-ary operation for each natural number $n$. Perhaps this is the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Do you have any references on the categorical theoretical aspects? I'd love to read more on this. And yes, if the tree monad is the free magma, then it would be the sort of info I've been looking for.

Comment: Would you know if the Free Monad over the List functor would provide the same thing?

Comment: @varkor I'd suggest talking about [_operads_](https://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf) instead of magmas. You'll get more search hits!

Comment: I'm not well versed on operads... Tried to get my head around them, but had a hard time. Any intro suggestions?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/what-is-an-operad-part-1). There probably are other expositions which might be more suitable depending on your background.

Comment: @Pedro: whoops, the term wasn't coming to mind, thanks!

Comment: I'm playing around doing some implementations, and it looks (for now) that a free monad over the List functor is doing the job... Any idea if this is indeed the case?/

Comment: @DaviBarreira: yes, that's correct. I've updated my answer with a few more details.